# REDcap: Seeking Efficient Solution for Bulk Deletion of REDCap Repeat Instances

Tags: redcap

I recently encountered an issue while working with REDCap and would appreciate your expertise in finding a streamlined solution. Here's a brief overview:

Inadvertently, I imported data into the wrong record_id for 999 repetitions of a form in REDCap. To rectify this, I imported the same CSV with empty data (retaining "record_id," "redcap_repeat_instrument," and "redcap_repeat_instance") and opted to overwrite the data with blank values. Consequently, I now have 999 empty repetitions in that specific record_id.

I've explored the API but couldn't find a direct way to delete a redcap_repeat_instance. While manually deleting repetitions one by one is an option, it's time-consuming. I'm curious if anyone has encountered a similar situation and found a more efficient method, perhaps through importing a CSV with specific information to facilitate bulk deletion?

Your insights and suggestions on this matter would be immensely valuable.

Best regards,
Álvaro

Comment: My preferred approach to this would be using the API.  Do you have permissions in your project to use the API?

Comment: Not in this project. However I have other projects with API permission. Could you please explain to me how to delete a redcap_repeat_instance using API? if other know how to do it without API would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the API and the R software, you can use the `redcapAPI` package to delete a record

```
library(redcapAPI)
rcon <- redcapConnection(url = [your api url], 
                         token = [your api token])

deleteRecord(rcon, 
             records = [record ids to delete], 
             arm = [arm number in which records are found. this is length 1], 
             api_param = list(event = [unique event name, length 1], 
                              repeat_instance = [repeat instance number, length 1]))
```

you'll need a separate call for each arm/event/repeat_instance combination.

Without access to the API, you'll have the most success talking to your REDCap Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

With API: as @Benjamin indicates, the "Delete Record" API method permits optional event/instrument/repeat_instance parameters to be supplied with the call that will restrict the delete to just the specified event/instrument/repeat_instance rather than the entire record.

If the API feels like overkill for a one-off process, you could do what you need via a process along these lines:

1. Download the data for the record in raw CSV format.
2. Remove anything you do not want to keep.
3. Change the record id and upload it as a new record.
4. Delete the original record.
5. Rename the new record so the record id becomes that of the original record.